# Hide char array values in C from memory debug

Tags: android, c, mobile, obfuscation, secret-key

Background:

I have an obfuscated C code. Obfuscation can only protect the algorithm logic, but cannot hide the variable values from dynamic analysis. I want to further hide some values (e.g., a char array) from memory debug.

Platform: mobile client-side (not related to remote server)

Assume I have a secret char array:

```
char secret[15] = {"hide this value"};
```

Is it possible to hide this value in this way:

- for every element i, secret[i] = x1[i] XOR x2[i]
- Only define and store char x1[ ] and char x2[ ] in the memory
- When need to use secret[ ] every time, call x1[ ] XOR x2[ ]. So secret[ ] cannot be found through memory debug (dynamic analysis)

Or any other ways?

Comment: Encrypt the data using OS-level functions. Windows: CryptProtectMemory().

Comment: @michael: sorry, I forgot to mention the mobile app platform

Comment: Tag it properly

Comment: Can you do the logic remotely?

Comment: @tay10r: it is client-side code only, not related to server-side

Comment: You can't really hide the data stored in memory when you're designing an app. The best you can do is zero it when it's not being used.

Comment: Are you trying to hide a software key verification or something? Obfuscation with XOR will be sufficient. Unless you are looking for military grade security type of thing, in which case obfuscation doesn't hide secrets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If an adversary has the ability to freely examine the working memory of your program, such as via a debugger, then within the program there are no secrets from them.  In particular, encrypting data in memory is not a reliable safeguard because you have to *de*crypt it to use it, at which point it can be easily be intercepted.  But also, the decryption key must be somewhere in memory, where your adversary can find it, thereby obtaining the ability to decrypt your in-memory encrypted data at will.

Obfuscating your code is not a reliable safeguard, either.  It may slow down your adversary, but with skill and / or good tools, they will sort out what's what in time.  In fact, supposing that you strip debugging symbols from the executable and do not provide source code, the only obfuscation that even is visible is external function and variable names (so don't bother obfuscating anything else).

Protect sensitive data by not putting it in unprivileged hands in the first place.  If you deliver data to an untrustworthy device or program, then you should consider it compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Anything you're discussing right now is just ways to obfuscate your data. If somebody wanted to debug or disassemble, they would clearly see what was happening and could find the key. Even without disassembly, seeing two strings, someone could XOR each character just out of curiosity. Given that, an XOR is still a good option and it keeps your data pretty obscure when both strings are unprintable. To further this, it would be interesting if you used a certain hash of a file or string to generate the key to XOR.

Now, given that, there are many resources on string obfuscation in binaries and in C that you can research.

Rather than obfuscation on its own, hashing or encryption could be used. This really depends on what the string/key is used for. If you are willing to comment more details, I can help out more.

Here are a few great resources:
 - [Stack Exchange: Protect Data Stored in Binary](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8793/protect-data-stored-in-binary)
 - [Binary/String Obfuscation in C](https://yurisk.info/2017/06/25/binary-obfuscation-string-obfuscating-in-C/index.html)